# Center Navbar links without brand pushing it to the right in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to center my navbar links but when i do my brand logo pushes it to the right so it is not centered. Heres my html ...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light main-nav">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand Name</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto clearfix">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

How can i stop the brand logo from affecting the position of my navbar links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of the way adjacent flexbox items position relative to each other.

One option is to use the flexbox utils, and a full width placeholder element on right. The navbar-brand is also set to full-width using `w-100` util class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable navbar-inverse bg-primary justify-content-center">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCenter">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a href class="navbar-brand d-flex w-100 mr-0">Brand is Wider Name</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCenter">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Center</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex w-100"> </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/N7veP8FMqg

Another option is to absolute position the `.navbar-nav`..

```
@media (min-width: 567px) {
    .abs-center-x {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/RCBftzZCD8

Related:
[Bootstrap 4 menu toggle button to left and right, with brand in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251513/bootstrap-4-menu-toggle-button-to-left-and-right-with-brand-in-center)
[How the LOGO could be CENTERED and Not collapsing and toggle icon should appear on left in the Navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911189/how-the-logo-could-be-centered-and-not-collapsing-and-toggle-icon-should-appear)