# Bootstrap 4 menu toggle button to left and right, with brand in center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar menu that looks like this on large screens:

[image]

And collapses to this on smaller screens:

[image]

But I would like to have one menu button to the left, the other menu button to the right, with the brand in the center. Like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is possible, and if so what the trick is?

**CODE (using bootstrap 4 beta):**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand logo-font" href="#">
        Brand
    </a>
    <!-- links toggle -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- account toggle --> 
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Other
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="account">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Link to Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/21PmzA2ff3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Bootstrap 4 does have a pretty neat trick for that. It's called reordering.

Replace the `ml-auto` class on the first navbar-toggler with the `order-first` class. This will put it as the first item.

Note: Moving the HTML code associated with the first navbar-toggler before the HTML for the navbar-brand would achieve the same effect. But I feel that using classes is more elegant and flexible instead of moving chunks of HTML code around.

The navbar-toggler only becomes visible when needed. That's why placing it first works well in this case.

Here's the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo-font" href="#">
            Brand
        </a>
        <!-- links toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler order-first" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#links" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- account toggle -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#account" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="links">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Other
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="account">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```