# Centering Brand string (or any other text item) in navbar? mx-auto gives strange results

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am having a hard time to center a title in the navbar component, two navbars with a button on the left side or without show two differently centered brands:

```
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">&lt;Index</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">News</a>
    </nav>
```

versus

```
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">News</a>
    </nav>
```

The [codeply snippet](https://www.codeply.com/go/Mt7heDhQni) shows how different these two navbars look. Is there a way to truly center a string as a title independently of the buttons left and right?

Comment: You can find an example fro this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912188/5319158

Comment: OK, I got it simplified to just one button and it works fine, thanks! https://www.codeply.com/go/RhWOkMopOo